# soap messages signing and encryption solution architecture

Tags: web-services, encryption, soap, sign, solution

I have faced a problem for implementing a scenario which I have.

There are some soap-based services and also some clients for them. Each client only uses one of the services.
In order to use the services each client has to apply both signing and encryption on the soap messages.

Actually I want to implement an application to avoid each client implementing these two processes.

I'm thinking about an application which resides between services and clients and does the signing and encryption, but I'm not sure about the best way of implementation.

It will be appreciated if anyone can help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try WS-Security and pick a configuration and implementation. Be warned that XML security is tricky to implement correctly. You need a good implementation and keep yourself up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
I have done the signing and encryption process, actually I’m using Java and a JAX-WS implementation (apache cxf) but what I’m looking for is a solution (or a kind of architecture or anything else which is correct) to avoid signing and encryption in every client.
As I said I want to do signing and encryption just once and use it in my every client.

Comment: I suppose you can program an application layer proxy for that, and use WS-security to send a particular SOAP message with the original message wrapped inside. But *configuring* WS-Security should not be too hard (and you'd need to configure the proxy services anyway). Glassfish, Tomcat and Microsoft Biztalk (apologies for using that name) etc. already have WS-Security implemented for it.